# Trying to print profile2 fields in other place error Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to print fields from profile2 module on the user page.

At present I have a profile called fun_profile (how ironic).

I am using the following code in a user-profile.tpl.php file in my theme.

```
<php $account = user_load($uid); $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account); print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['fun_profile'], 'field_eye_colour'));?>
```

I am trying to print out the field eye colour on the user page.

I have basic html text printing the word - Hookum - to make sure I was in the right area.

Essentially I am trying to print the user picture from a field created in profile2 and use that in place of the user picture from user-profile....but that is away down the road.

I thought I could start small and work up.

I keep getting an error:

Notice: Undefined variable: uid in include() (line 43 of C:\Users\tony\Sites\acquia-drupal\sites\all\themes\skeletonthemeOmallyes\templates\user-profile.tpl.php).
Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 178 of C:\Users\tony\Sites\acquia-drupal\includes\entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 355 of C:\Users\tony\Sites\acquia-drupal\includes\entity.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: fun_profile in include() (line 43 of C:\Users\tony\Sites\acquia-drupal\sites\all\themes\skeletonthemeOmallyes\templates\user-profile.tpl.php).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type profile2. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7633 of C:\Users\tony\Sites\acquia-drupal\includes\common.inc).

The code:

```
<php
global $user;
$uid = user_load($user->uid);
$profile_main = profile2_load_by_user($uid, 'fun_profile'); ?>


<php
print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile_fun_profile, 'field_eye_colour', 'value'));?>
```

Prints out the value for the eye colour - but the value doesn't change as I view other user-profiles - guessing due to the global.

Any help would be great,

Tony.

Comment: That's because $user is you, who are browsing the website.